# Angularjs - Unknown provider:

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

I keep getting this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: UsersServiceProvider <- UsersService
```

I read about this topic in https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr so i put ['UsersService' before my controller function, but didnt get it to work. 
This is my code, i have only run `yo angular`  and then `yo angular:service users`.

This is in my controllers/main.js

```
angular.module('pmsFrontApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['UsersService',function ($scope, UsersService) {

    $scope.form = { firstName: '', lastName: '' };
    UsersService.fetchAll().then(function(data) {
    //console.log(data);
    //$scope.lista = data;
  });
}]);
```

and this is in my services/users.js

```
angular.module('pmsFrontApp')
  .service('UsersService', function ($q,$http) {
    this.fetchAll = function() {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      $http.get('http://localhost:8888/users', /*{
        params: {}
      }*/).success(function(data) {
        defer.resolve(data);
      }).error(function() {
        defer.reject('No vieja');
      });

      return defer.promise;
    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needs to look like this

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'UsersService', function ($scope, UsersService) {
```

You are injecting both `$scope` and your service.  You need to mention both by name, and then inject them in the same order in the function.

In your example, your `$scope` variable is actually your UsersService.

Comment: Thanks, i knew it coulnd't be that magical. It solved my problem. Now i get another one related to access control allow origin, but i can work that out i think.